# merge the object of two arrays which are nested

Tags: javascript

**would like to merge the objects of arrays.**

```
var arr1 = [
    {nested: {first: "aaa"}},
    {nested: {first: "bbb"}},
    {nested: {first: "ccc"}}
];
var arr2 = [
    {nested: {last: "zzz"}},
    {nested: {last: "yyy"}}
];
```

**been trying to merge this way to no avail:**

```
arr1.map((item, i) => {
    return Object.assign({}, 
    {firstName: item.nested.first},
    {lastName: arr2[i].nested.last}) 
})
```

**would like this:**

```
[
    {first: "aaa", last: "zzz"},
    {first: "bbb", last: "yyy"}
    {first: "ccc"}
];
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to iterate and map the values back to merge each object in the arrays

```js
var arr1 = [
    {nested: {first: "aaa"}},
    {nested: {first: "bbb"}},
    {nested: {first: "ccc"}}
];
var arr2 = [
    {nested: {last: "zzz"}},
    {nested: {last: "yyy"}}
];

var arr3 = arr1.map( (obj,index) => {
    return Object.assign({}, obj.nested, arr2[index] && arr2[index].nested||{});
});

console.log(arr3)
```

Note that this assumes the first array is longer than the second, if that's not a given, you'd have to check the length and start with the array with the greatest length.

Comment: yeah, that's it.

you've added: || {} at the end.

you slick bastard you...thank you :)